# Secondary disk got duplicated in /media/username

Tags: mount, debian, media

I just ran my system like everyday and permissions for my secondary disk changed, my user wasn't able to access to it, so I changed ownership of the disk. After that I checked in `/media/username/` and I saw two disks. One is `Secondary Disk` and the new one is `Secondary Disk1`. First one is empty and I tried to mount/unmount it and I got this:

When trying to mount:

```
mount: can't find /media/zevensource/Secondary Disk in /etc/fstab
```

When trying to unmount:

```
umount: /media/zevensource/Secondary Disk: not mounted
```

How can I remove the empty one? I've got few programs that need to access the secondary disk and now all the paths are wrong because of the name change.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the empty 'one' is probably just a directory.  when you mount a device; its mounted onto a directory (from GUI the 'directory' is often created/deleted automatically hence users don't notice it).  the command to delete it is `rmdir`  (which may need sudo).  the be sure; `ls -lha /media/username/` (long format, all, human-readable; only -l should be needed) and its first character will be a 'd' for directory; - for file; if its special it may be a device as you claim).  I'd put an entry in `/etc/fstab` (file system table) so it always mounts where you want automatically.

Comment: `so I changed ownership of the disk`: how did you do this? This may be were the duplicate is being created from.